# Connects to Outlook and Skype but not to web sites

Tags: internet-connection

I am having an issue when I connect my laptop hard wired to internet, My Skype and Outlook have connection and are connected to internet just fine but I have problem with connecting to websites through browser or if I ping it, it will say request timed out.

What are some places I can look to troubleshoot and debug ?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is this specific to your network connection?

Comment: @bithakr I tried both Chrome and IE.  Even when I want to connect to our TFS in Visual Studio have the same problem. Sometimes it connects, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm.. so its not at the application level. Could it be that for some reason eiher HTTP or HTTPS is working but not both?

Comment: Which OS you're using and it is working on another device ?

Comment: Windows 7 I am on.